# the poll() system call blocks when i send a lot of requests to my server

Tags: http, sockets, webserver, polling, multiplexing

I made a simple HTTP server that waits for requests and sends a small HTTP response and I want it to handle multiple requests.

I made the fd non-blocking and I poll before doing any operation but the server still blocks after some requests

the test stops after some requests  it never ends i always need to kill the process or:[image: screenshot]

I used siege to test the server as follows:

```
siege --verbose --reps="1000" --concurrent=100 http:localhost:8080
```

this is my code :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/_types/_socklen_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_ssize_t.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int create_connection(int port)
{
    int yes=1;
    struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
    int listen_fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (listen_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("webserv(socket)");
        return -1;
    }
    host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    host_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int host_addrlen = sizeof(host_addr);

    if (setsockopt(listen_fd,SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) != 0)
    {
        perror("webserv(setsockopt)");
        return -1;
    }
    if (bind(listen_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&host_addr,host_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        perror("webserv(bind)");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fcntl(listen_fd,F_SETFD,O_NONBLOCK) == -1)
    {
        perror("webserv(fcntl)");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(listen_fd,128) == -1)
    {
        perror("webserv(listen)");
        return -1;

    }
    return listen_fd;
}

void run_server(int listen_fd)
{
    int nb_of_fds = 0;
    struct pollfd fds[1024];
    fds[nb_of_fds].fd = listen_fd;
    fds[nb_of_fds].events = POLLIN;
    nb_of_fds++;
    struct sockaddr communication;

    std::ifstream f("./younes/www/html/index.html");
    std::string body = "<html>  <body> <h1>test<h1> </body> </html>\r\n";
    if (f)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << f.rdbuf();
        body = ss.str();
    }
    std::string msg = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    msg += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    msg += "Content-Length:" + std::to_string(body.length()) + "\r\n";
    msg += "\r\n";
    msg += body;

    while (1)
    {
        int ret = poll(fds,nb_of_fds,2000);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            perror("webserv(poll)");
            return ;
        }
        else if (!ret)
            continue;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nb_of_fds;i++)
            {
                if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN)
                {
                    //std::cout << "pollin" << std::endl;
                        socklen_t addr_size = sizeof communication;
                        int fd_client = accept(listen_fd,&communication,&addr_size);
                        if (fd_client == -1)
                        {
                            perror("webserv(accept)");
                            return ;
                        }


                        char buf[1000011];
                        ssize_t s = recv(fd_client,buf,1000000,0);
                        buf[s] = 0;

                        // add the client fd to struct
                        fds[nb_of_fds].fd = fd_client;
                        fds[nb_of_fds].events = POLLOUT;
                        nb_of_fds++;
                }
                if (fds[i].revents & POLLOUT)
                {

                    if (send(fds[i].fd,msg.c_str(),msg.length(),MSG_OOB) == -1)
                    {
                        perror("webserv(send)");
                        return ;
                    }

                    close(fds[i].fd);
                    for (int j = i;j < nb_of_fds - 1;j++)
                    {
                        fds[j].fd =  fds[j + 1].fd;
                        fds[j].events =  fds[j + 1].events;
                        fds[j].revents =  fds[j + 1].revents;
                    }
                    fds[nb_of_fds -1].revents = 0;
                    fds[nb_of_fds -1].fd = 0;
                    fds[nb_of_fds -1].events = 0;
                    nb_of_fds--;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct pollfd fds[1024];
    int listen_fd;

    if (argc == 2)
        listen_fd = create_connection(atoi(argv[1]));
    else
        listen_fd = create_connection(8080);

    if (listen_fd > 0)
    {
        run_server(listen_fd);
        close(listen_fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I made the fd non-blocking ...

You make only the `listen_fd` non-blocking, but not the `fd_client`. Note that non-blocking behavior gets not inherited within `accept`.

> ... and I poll before doing any operation but the server still blocks after some requests

In the following part of the code you call `recv` on the blocking file descriptor `client_fd` w/o doing a poll first.

```
                    int fd_client = accept(listen_fd,&communication,&addr_size);
                    ...
                    ssize_t s = recv(fd_client,buf,1000000,0);
                    buf[s] = 0;
```

Apart from that you don't properly check `recv` for error, in which case `s` would be `-1` and you would write out of the bounds of the array `buf`.

Comment: I did what you said but the same problem occurs : [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/A5VJ1GR)

Comment: @younesaskour: *"I did what you said"* - I have no idea what exactly you did.  But please debug your server to check what the server is actually doing instead of only looking at the output from your client.